# Adding MarkerClustererPlus to existing Google Maps API embedded code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm looking to add clustering to a google Maps API embed that I have on a webflow website.  Is anyone able to explain how I would implement this ( https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform-101-js#5 ). I'm not sure what to do in step one when it states 'Import the marketcluster' with it being an embed. Is it even possibly with this solution?

Here's the current set up... https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nz14hubc/1/

```js
// Variables for Google maps
var map, mapElem, markerImg, infoWindow, marker;
var markers = [], infoWindows = [], 
races = [{lat: 40.7127753, lng: -74.0059728, url:""},
{lat: 40.735657, lng:-74.1723667, url:""}];
var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  //zoom: 13,
  //scrollwheel: false,
  styles: [
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#444444"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 45
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#2bb0e6"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
}
]
  
};

function initialize() {
  markerImg = {
    url:'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f58a4616a9e71d63ca059c8/5fa18680b95c219254ad0c9c_place-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(46, 57),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(23, 54),
  }
                  
  // Display a map on the page
  mapElem = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);
  
  

  // Loop through our array of races
  for(i = 0; i < races.length; i++) {
    var race = races[i];
  
    // Generate an infowindow content for the marker
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(
      '<div class="bg-race"</div>' +
      '<p>'+race.name+'<br>Next race: '+race.date+'</p>' +
      '<a href="'+race.url+'" target="_new"> Race wesbsite </a>'
    );
    infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
  
    // Place a marker on the map
    createMarker(race.lat, race.lng, i);
  }
  
  // Center the map fitting all markers on the screen
  fitToMarkers();
}

function createMarker(x, y, i) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: markerImg,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
    title: races[i].name
  });
  marker._index = i;
  markers.push(marker);
  
  // Click event on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      // Close last opened infowindow if any
      if(infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
      // Open clicked infowindow
      infoWindow = infoWindows[i];
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function fitToMarkers() {
  map.setZoom(13);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(13); // zoom out when done so markers on the top can be seen
}

/*
// When Webflow has loaded,
Webflow.push(function() {

    // Resize event
  $(window).resize(function() {
  
    // Do nothing if mobile
    if($(window).width() < 768) return;

    // Resize map if function is defined
    if(typeof mapResize === 'function') mapResize();
  });
  
  
  
});
*/
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIwzALxUPNbatRBj3Xi1Uhp0fFzwWNBkE&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial: [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) would probably be more useful for your example.

1. Include the MarkerClusterer script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
```

(or you can use a version from a different CDN)

2. Instantiate a MarkerClusterer:

```
// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath:
      "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nz14hubc/2/)

(note: commented out the `fitToMarkers` call and set the zoom and center so it would show the cluster)

[image: screenshot of resulting map, zoomed out]

```js
// Variables for Google maps
var map, mapElem, markerImg, infoWindow, marker;
var markers = [], infoWindows = [], 
races = [{lat: 40.7127753, lng: -74.0059728, url:""},
{lat: 40.735657, lng:-74.1723667, url:""}];
var mapOptions = {
  center: races[0], // add center to initialize map
  zoom: 8,          // zoom out so can see cluster
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  //zoom: 13,
  //scrollwheel: false,
  styles: [
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#444444"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 45
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#2bb0e6"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
}
]
  
};

function initialize() {
  markerImg = {
    url:'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f58a4616a9e71d63ca059c8/5fa18680b95c219254ad0c9c_place-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(46, 57),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(23, 54),
  }
                  
  // Display a map on the page
  mapElem = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);
  
  

  // Loop through our array of races
  for(i = 0; i < races.length; i++) {
    var race = races[i];
  
    // Generate an infowindow content for the marker
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(
      '<div class="bg-race"</div>' +
      '<p>'+race.name+'<br>Next race: '+race.date+'</p>' +
      '<a href="'+race.url+'" target="_new"> Race wesbsite </a>'
    );
    infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
  
    // Place a marker on the map
    createMarker(race.lat, race.lng, i);
  }
  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/images/m',
  });
  // Center the map fitting all markers on the screen
  // fitToMarkers(); // comment out so can see clustering
}

function createMarker(x, y, i) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: markerImg,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
    title: races[i].name
  });
  marker._index = i;
  markers.push(marker);
  
  // Click event on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      // Close last opened infowindow if any
      if(infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
      // Open clicked infowindow
      infoWindow = infoWindows[i];
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function fitToMarkers() {
  map.setZoom(13);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(13); // zoom out when done so markers on the top can be seen
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```